# OSB- make proxy process one request at a time

Tags: oracle, concurrency, osb

I have an FTP file polling proxy service in OSB. I want to make it process one file at a time. So for example, if in the directory there are 10 new files, I want the proxy service to grab the first file (FTP and perform all consequent steps) and only after that to grab the next file. Is it possible to enforce this control in OSB?

Answer (score 0):

The JCA adaptor can be set up for single-threaded use:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/integration.1111/e10231/adptr_file.htm#BABGDDAE